# Android add ID to a layout

Tags: android, layout

How do I define an ID to a layout?

I am trying to add an ID to a linearlayout and setting an onclick listener:

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/?????????"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:onClick="btnHandler" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //....

    public void btnHandler(View v){
       switch(v)
       {
          case R.id.????? :
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the ID is not your problem here, you have tu put the layout `android:clickable=true` because you are already adding the id, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have this

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:onClick="btnHandler" >
</LinearLayout>
```

You can do as below

```
  public void btnHandler(View v)
  {
      switch(v.getId()) // use v.getId()
   {
      case R.id.linearlayout :
      break;  // also don't forget the break;
   }

  }
```

Edit:

If you have button then you can do as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:onClick="clickEvent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bt1"
    android:text="button"   
    android:onClick="clickEvent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity

```
public void clickEvent(View v)
{
       switch(v.getId())
       {
          case R.id.linearlayout :
              Log.i("......"," linear layout clicked");
          break; 
          case R.id.bt1 :
        Log.i("......"," button clicked");
            break;
       }
}
```

Comment: I want to add an onClickListener to the layout and not to a button.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian sorry mistook.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
switch(v)
```

use

```
switch(v.getId())
```

and set your id from the xml

```
android:id="@+id/idValue"
```

Comment: Good catch, my friend. Although its fairly obvious to those who know why, maybe you could add a short explanation to what its doing...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to just add it in your layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/myId" <!-- the part where the id is being created -->
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:onClick="btnHandler" >
</LinearLayout>
```

It can then be referenced from your code via `your.package.R.id.myId`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/lineaLayoutId"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:onClick="btnHandler" >
</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //....

    public void btnHandler(View v){
       switch(v)
       {
          case R.id.lineaLayoutId :
          break;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate() of your Activity:

```
findViewById(R.id.?????????).setOnClickListener(this);
```

And have your Activity implement View.OnClickListener.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.?????????) {
        //your code for on click
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work..

XML

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/mylayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    LinearLayout myLayout = findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
    myLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click over Layout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

}